# Problem regarding using Gillespie algorithm with python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm working on a problem considering two events (`W`, `M`) and try to calculate the time decay from `W` to `M` using Gillespie. This is pictorial representation of the problem.

[image]

I solved this using these code:

```py
RMW = 1
RWM = 0.35
t = []

for i in range (0,10000):
    if (i%2) == 0: #W present
        tM = 0
        dt = expon.rvs(RWM, size=1)
        tM += dt
    else:
        tW = 0
    dt = expon.rvs(RMW, size=1)
    tW += dt
    t.append(dt)
```

Now I'm moving to a more complicated problem where there are three events (`W`, `M1` and `M2`). The rates are also different like `RWM1=0.35` and `RWM2=0.1`. This is the pictorial representation.

[image]

Now I'm not able to understand from where I should start. It will be very helpful if someone can give me some suggestion based on the previous code to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: should the value of **dt** add up for `M2W` --->  `M2M1` and `WM1` --->  `M2M1`?

Comment: Yes, the value of dt add up for M2W ---> M2M1 and WM1 ---> M2M1

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `dt` is supposed to add up as you've said, does this probably solve your problem?

```py
RMW = 1
RWM = 0.35
t = []

for i in range (0,10000):
    if (i%2) == 0: #W present
        tM = 0
        dt = expon.rvs(WM1, size=1)
        dt += expon.rvs(WM1_M2M1, size=1)
        tM += dt
    else:
        tW = 0
        dt = expon.rvs(M2M, size=1)
        dt += expon.rvs(M2M_M2M1, size=1)
        tW += dt
    t.append(dt)
```

Comment: Thank you. If these values do not add up. What will be my approach?

Comment: That'd depend on how the events are interlinked. In this case the numbers of paths are only two(although a two step process), just like the code that you had initially there wasn't much to do. Do you have any specific problem or other requirements?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes, I have different conditions. This is one condition when the value of dt does not add up for M2W ---> M2M1 and WM1 ---> M2M.       The rate RWM1 = 0.20 (WM1 ---> M2M1)and RWM2 =0.1 (M2W ---> M2M1) which are different from from the rates (RWM1=0.35, WW--> WM1 and RWM2=0.05 for WW--> WM2)values are different.

Comment: Also, is there a way to add "coupling value" between W, M1 and M2 in the code. So, that based on that value, the rate will change for the reaction WM1 --> M2M1 and M2W --> M2M1.

Comment: Hello and sorry for my late reply. I think a state machine based approach would be a very elegant solution to your problem. Do have a look at https://pypi.org/project/python-statemachine/ using which you can control the events transition and also control the methods that are executed during event transition using callbacks.